# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'false' when building an Angular app in the terminal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using an Angular (not AngularJS) application that I run via the terminal using the `ng serve` command.

Everything builds and I can navigate to the Angular app locally through my browser, however when looking at the terminal I have noticed there are some build errors displayed in red displayed below.

```
✔ Compiled successfully.
⠋ Generating browser application bundles...
    Error: src/app/components/posting/posting.component.ts:343:78 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'false | Promise<unknown>'.
      Property 'then' does not exist on type 'false'.

    343 this.getVideoMediaData(file).then(a => this.validateFileAgainstConfig('instagram'));
                                                                                     ~~~~
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
```

My `getVideoMediaData()` looks like this

```
    public getVideoMediaData(file) {
        if (typeof file === 'undefined') {
            return false;
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.postingService.getMetadata(file.url).subscribe(
                data => {
                    resolve(data);
                    const errors = data.errors;
                    file.errors = [];
                    if (errors && errors.length > 0 ) {
                        errors.forEach(function(ffmpegError) {
                            file.errors.push({
                                'message': ffmpegError,
                                'validation': 'ffmpeg'
                            });
                        }, this);
                    }
                },
                errorResponse => {
                    reject(errorResponse);
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

What is causing this & how would be the best approach to fix this issue so I no longer receive this error in the terminal once it has finished building after running ng serve.

*Expected outcome*
After running ng serve the app builds without any errors

*Actual outcome* After running ng serve the app builds and displays the "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'false'" error in the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first if doesn't return a `Promise`. Wrap `false` with `Promise.resolve(false)` or make the method `async` and you should be fine.

Side-note:

You should check for `truthyness` of file as it also considers `null` besides from `undefined`:

```js
async getVideoMediaData(file): Promise<boolean> {
        if (!file) return false;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.postingService.getMetadata(file.url).subscribe(
                data => {
                    resolve(data);
                    const errors = data.errors;
                    file.errors = [];
                    if (errors && errors.length > 0 ) {
                        errors.forEach(function(ffmpegError) {
                            file.errors.push({
                                'message': ffmpegError,
                                'validation': 'ffmpeg'
                            });
                        }, this);
                    }
                },
                errorResponse => {
                    reject(errorResponse);
                }
            );
        });

}
```

Side-note-2:

You should also consider `toPromise()` (RxJS 6 and lower) or `firstValueFrom` (RxJS 7^) to transform that service observable into a `Promise`

```js
async getVideoMediaData(file): Promise<boolean> {
        if (!file) return false;

        // if using RxJS 6 or lower
        const data = await this.postingService.getMetadata(file.url).toPromise()
        // RxJS 7
        const data = await firstValueFrom(
            this.postingService.getMetadata(file.url)
        )
        const errors = data.errors;
        file.errors = [];
        if (errors && errors.length > 0 ) {
            errors.forEach(function(ffmpegError) {
                 file.errors.push({
                     'message': ffmpegError,
                     'validation': 'ffmpeg'
                  });
            }, this);
         }
       return data
}
```

Side-note-3:

I suggest you restrain yourself from passing anonymous functions and use `fat-arrows` when dealing with JS arrays as you don't have to deal with the `this` mess that JS has. Also using `map` is better than `for-each`ing and pushing:

```js
file.errors = Array.from(data.errors ?? []).map(ffmpegError => ({message: ffmpegError, validation: 'ffmpeg'}))
```

Comment: that is a great explanation thank you - i will accept this shortly